# Adding scope parameter to onclick function inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onclick, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to pass a parameter to a function called via `onclick` inside a `ng-repeat` :

```
 <!-- Sliding bar (bottom) -->
<div ng-show="currentSVG && currentLanguage && currentWidth && bannerHeight" pageslide ps-open="bottomBar" ps-side="bottom" ps-speed="0.3" align="center">
    <div id="related" class="content mThumbnailScroller" style="padding-top: 5px" ng-show="currentSVG && currentLanguage">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="lastSVG in svgHistory track by $index">{{lastSVG}}<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeSVG({{lastSVG}})"><img src="../downloads/PNG/{{currentLanguage}}/{{lastSVG}}.png"  width="{{currentWidth * 0.1}}" height="{{bannerHeight * 0.65}}" title="{{lastSVG}}" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I give the parameter `lastSVG` to my `changeSVG()` function in my `onclick` ?

`changeSVG()` is not in the controller. It works fine if I manuelly set a parameter.

Also, it doesnt work with `ng-click` instead of `onclick`

Here is the `changeSVG` function : **(The function is NOT in the controller)**

```
function    changeSVG(svgName, defaultZoom){
    if (!defaultZoom)
        defaultZoom = 1;
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('container')).scope();
    scope.currentSVG = svgName;
    scope.currentZoom = defaultZoom;
    if (scope.svgHistory.indexOf(svgName) === -1)
        if (scope.svgHistory.unshift(svgName) > 20)
            scope.svgHistory = scope.svgHistory.slice(0, 20);
    localStorage.setItem("svgHistory", JSON.stringify(scope.svgHistory));
    removeEmbed();
    var svgPath = "../SVG/" + scope.currentLanguage + "/" + svgName + ".svg";
    lastEmbed = createNewEmbed(svgPath, defaultZoom);
}
```

Comment: just use lastSVG without braces and with ng-click, the ng-click directive will look for a lastSVG property on the scope and will find it

Comment: @NexusDuck Hi, thx for the quick reply but nope, it doesnt work this way. lastSVG is actually not in the scope, it's set for the loop in the ng-repeat. svgHistory is an array and is in the scope. lastSVG is just the different value of the array one by one (if I'm not mistaken in ng-repeat behavior).

Answer (score 0):

The ng-click directive without braces should do the trick:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="changeSVG(lastSVG)">
```

The ng-click directive will look for any properties on the scope named lastSVG and will find it (since ng-repeat creates a new scope for every repetition)

A working plunkr example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/W9WcWoNK9IrJWMjw8ryq?p=preview

Comment: Hi, thx for the quick reply but nope, it doesnt work this way. lastSVG is actually not in the scope, it's set for the loop in the ng-repeat. svgHistory is an array and is in the scope. lastSVG is just the different value of the array one by one (if I'm not mistaken in ng-repeat behavior).

Comment: ng-repeat will create a new scope for every repetition, you can check it manually with an extension like Batarang

Comment: Well, the question becomes then how do I access ng-repeat inherent scope ? Because `changeSVG(lastSVG)`is basically trying to access this scope I believe.

Comment: It will look in the correct scope, every html element you duplicate with ng-repeat will have its own scope where lastSVG will be accessible, see my added plnkr example

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, could you add your controller code? Perhaps there's a mistake in your changeSVG function

Comment: I edited the initial post and added it, but like I said before, the function is not inside the controller.

Comment: Why would you not put that function in the controller? Any functions you call from an angular view should be declared in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to change my code and make the function inside the controller in order to make it work.
But I still wonder how this could be achieved if we wanna do it with a function external to the controller.